# Override GlobalPipes

Tags: nestjs

How override globalpipes. I tried this one, but not work :(

```
// main.ts
async function bootstrap() {
      const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
      app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
      await app.listen(3000);
}
```

And this is how I override the global.

```
// mycontroller
@Put(":id")
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ groups: ["must_only"] }))
async change(@Body() userDTO: UserDTO, @Param('id') id) {
    //.... some code
}
```